# "99 99" permissions on Mac OS X shared drive

Tags: 12.04, macosx, shared-folders

I have Mac OS X Lion and Ubuntu 12.04 installed on two separate SSDs with the my Mac OS X data on a HDD. I disabled journaling on the data drive, installed the necessary drivers, and modified the fstab--now the data drive mounts in Ubuntu with read/write access. Further, I've modified my Ubuntu user's uid(502) and gid(20) to match that of the Mac user.

However, I noticed that while some files have the correct permissions in Ubuntu (user:dialout), others are set as 99:99. I can change these to user:dialout from Ubuntu, but any time I create a new file or folder in Mac OS X, the permission is 99:99 in Ubuntu. Is there a way around this without changing permissions every time I want to modify a file from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150529200446/http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2007/03/user-99-unknown.html) helped explain the purpose of the 99:99 permissions. In order to get around it I had to select *Ignore ownership on this volume* in the Get Info window. After that I changed the ownership as desgua suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the files are owned by no one. So the command you should use is something like: `sudo chown -R bobby:bobby /path/to/the/folder` where "bobby" is your user name.